# Adding MVC DropdownList HTML Helper Dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add DropDownList helper dynamically using jQuery

This code i wrote successfully create the dropdown lists as needed, however code render the  HTML tags in unexpected format, where it places double quotes for each attributes' value!! (e.g name=""HousingUnitCount"")

```
<select class="&quot;form-control" input-sm&quot;="" id="&quot;HousingUnitCount&quot;" name="&quot;HousingUnitCount&quot;"><option value="&quot;&quot;">Choose the number of housing Unit</option>
<option value="&quot;0&quot;">0</option>
<option value="&quot;1&quot;">1</option>
<option value="&quot;2&quot;">2</option>
<option value="&quot;3&quot;">3</option>
<option value="&quot;4&quot;">4</option>
<option value="&quot;5&quot;">5</option>
</select>
```

Below is the code i have,

Here I am defining global variables for my list and HTML Helper to be used in jQuery

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "TestingDynamicFormWithjQuery";

var unitsCountList = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem() {Text="0", Value="0"},
                                                new SelectListItem() {Text="1", Value="1"},    
                                                new SelectListItem() {Text="2", Value="2"},
                                                new SelectListItem() {Text="3", Value="3"},
                                                new SelectListItem() {Text="4", Value="4"},
                                                new SelectListItem() {Text="5", Value="5"}
                                              };

var housingUnit = Html.DropDownList("HousingUnitCount", unitsCountList, "Choose the number of housing Unit", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-sm" }).ToHtmlString();
}
```

This is the HTML i am using

```
<button id="addUnitBtn" type="button" name="addUnitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Unit
</button>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div id="addUnitDiv">

    </div>

    <br/><br /><br />
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
}
```

Below is the jQuery code to add DropDownList dynamically

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function () {
        console.log('windows ready');
        $('button[name="addUnitBtn"]').on("click", function () {
            console.log('btn clicked');
            $("#addUnitDiv").append('<div>@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(housingUnit)</div>');
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: `JavaScriptStringEncode` will encode the string. Do you need to encode it?

Comment: Then how can i embed an HTML helper in Javascript code without using JavaScriptStringEncode ? i tried to embed the mvc helper without using JavaScriptStringEncode and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
 <script type="text/html" id="template">
       <div class="template-wrapper">
            @Html.DropDownList("HousingUnitCount", unitsCountList, "Choose the number of housing Unit", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-sm"})
       </div>

    </script>
```

then in your javascript code :

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function () {
        console.log('windows ready');
        $('button[name="addUnitBtn"]').on("click", function () {
            console.log('btn clicked');

            var $template = $.trim($($('#template').html()));

             updateTemplateElementsNameAttr($template);

            $("#addUnitDiv").append($template);
        });
    });

function updateTemplateElementsNameAttr($template){
    var nextIndex = $('.template-wrapper').length;

    $template.find('select').each(function(){
     var nameAttr = $(this).attr('name') + '[' + nextIndex + ']';
     $(this).attr('name', nameAttr);

    }
}
</script>
}
```

Comment: That's a gr8 answer, and it did work for me, however using script template doesn't give me the option to have dynamic generated attribut names (eg dynamiclly prefixing drop down list names with numbers ([0], [1]...) to allow binding ing to ICollection)

Comment: For that you need to update name attributes for each template with jquery. I have updated my answer.